# product of topological spaces

Tags: general-topology

I was just wondering, if $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is a closed subset of the topological space $Y,$ where $f$ is the function mapping $f:X\rightarrow Y$, then is the product $X\times A$ also a closed subset of $X\times Y?$ (Note $Y$ here is compact and Hausdorff)

Quite frankly, in the notes it says it is closed but I do not know why it is the case, can anyone help me explain why it is the case?

Comment: What's the role of $f$ here? -- Anyway, as the projections are continuous and $X\times A$ is the inverse image of $A$ under the projection  $X\times Y\to Y$, ...

Comment: Im sorry I do not understand your answer, so is it closed? I know continuous maps map a closed subset to a closed subset, but not sure about the product case.

Comment: Continuous maps do not necessarily map closed sets to closed sets. Preimages of closed sets wrt continuous maps are closed, yes. Here $X\times A=p^{-1}(A)$ where $p$ is the projection $X\times Y\to Y$. It is continuous. So indeed $X\times A$ is closed if $A$ is closed.

Comment: So are you saying since $\pi_Y^{-1}:A\rightarrow X\times A$ is the inverse map, wrt to the continuous map $\pi_Y,$ and since $A$ is closed, then $X\times A$ is closed?

Comment: It’s the inverse image under $p$, not the “inverse map” which does not exist here.

Comment: No. $\pi_Y$ is not bijective hence has no inverse. The notation $\pi_Y^{-1}(A)$ denotes the set $\{(x,y)\mid \pi_Y(x,y)\in A\}=\{(x,y)\mid y\in A\}=X\times A$. In my former comment $p=\pi_Y$.

Comment: Ok now I am confused there is an answer below which says no, and the comment section says yes...

Comment: Your question is unclear. You mention a function $f$ but after that you ask a question about $X\times A$ and the $f$ is not referred to anymore. If your question is $A\text{ closed }\implies X\times A\text{ closed }$?? then the answer is: yes. If that is enough then do not pay attention to the answer of aciba.

Comment: Ok, then it seems like my question has been answered, thank you for all the help :).

Answer (score -1):

Your question should be: is $X \times f(A) $ close subset of $X \times Y $? And the answer is no, $f$ has to be continuous and open or close mapping.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).